# Asp.net Identity v2 with custom authentication service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm building a MVC website (with EPiServer) that I initially set up with a custom membership and role provider that call a REST service for user validation and permissions.

However, it seems we could benefit by changing to Microsoft's Asp.net Identity v2 for claims based auth. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to arrange Asp.net Identity 2 to use the same REST service for user validation and generating the claims. Most examples on the web are specific to using OWIN and Entity Framework which don't seem relevant for what I need.

Could someone point me in the right direction to figure out how to utilise Asp.net Identity v2 but with integrating our REST service for the user validation and permissions/claims? I feel that I should only need https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and to make a custom UserStore that talks to the REST service, but I'm not confident due to lack of clear examples or documents (or maybe it's just me) to implement it.

Hope this is a clear question - let me know if there's anything other info that could help improve the discussion.

Comment: I'd start here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx Implement `IUserStore` as a wrapper for your REST service.

Comment: Hi @trailmax - thanks for the tip, that link looks like an ideal read - will report back with how it goes :)

Comment: @MatthewBoniface, I'm curious whether you were successful in using ASP.NET Identity to achieve this.  I'm in a similar boat (need to use  REST service as user/role store).

Comment: @Jiveman Sorry but we didn't end up following through with this (decided to leave it with conventional membership provider). Hope you have luck with it!